# Selenium field locator

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can someone help me to locate a link field
test website:  http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php
username: admin
password: demo123

test case: click on Posts on left had side panel and then click Add new.

I am unable to locate 'Posts' link after login. Script is throwing this error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
public class NewPost {

WebDriver driver;

    public NewPost(WebDriver localdriver){
        this.driver = localdriver;
    }

    WebElement box=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu-posts']/a")); 
    List<WebElement> links = box.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    WebElement posts = links.get(1);


    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='wpbody-content']/div[4]/h2/a")
    WebElement addNew;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='title']")
    WebElement postTitle;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='content']")
    WebElement content;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='publish']")
    WebElement publishButton;

    @FindBy(how=How.ID, using="message")
    WebElement postPublishedMsg;

    public void addNewPost(String titleText, String contentText){

        posts.click();
        addNew.click();
        postTitle.sendKeys(titleText);
        content.sendKeys(contentText);
        publishButton.click();

        if(postPublishedMsg.getText().contains("Post published")){
            System.out.println("Post published successfully");
        }


    }


}
```

Test class:

```
@Test
public class VerifyNewPost {

    public void checkNewPost(){

        WebDriver driver = BrowserFactory.startBrowser("firefox", "http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php");

        LoginPageNew login_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageNew.class);

        login_page.loginWordpress("admin", "demo123");

        NewPost post = PageFactory.initElements(driver, NewPost.class);

        post.addNewPost("This is new post title", "This is new Post content");


    }
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but I would recommend the Codeception framework. Then it would be as easy like this: $I->click('Posts');

Answer (score 0):

In order to click on Add New button you have to hover the mouse on Post link first.

You can achieve this using Actions class.

**Please Try this:**

```
WebElement postlink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Posts')]"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(postlink);
// Click on 'Add New' button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-posts']//a[contains(text(),'Add New')]")).click();
```

I didn't use Page Factory. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

1. Once you are on the [Dashboard](http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-admin/) page click on `Posts` link, where the element as per PageFactory is:

   ```
   @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//li[@id='menu-posts']/a")
   WebElement posts;
   ```
2. Construct the method to click on `Posts` link:

   ```
   public void click_Posts()
   {
       posts.click();
       System.out.println("Clicked on Posts on Dashboard page");
   }
   ```
3. Now from `VerifyNewPost` class call the `click_Posts()` method to perform the click on `Posts` link.
4. Keep a watch, after logging into the site you are on `Dashboard` page where you need to define the Page Objects and the relevant methods.
5. On `Dashboard` page when you click on `Posts` link, you are redirected to [Posts](http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php) page where you need to define the Page Objects and the relevant methods in order to click on `Add New` link.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.